# Consulta está repetindo resultados - SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou fazendo uma consulta no meu bd SQLite, mas está me retornando alguns resultados repetidos não consigo achar o erro.

```
 cursor = db.Select(DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + " LEFT JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_SITUACAO + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_SITUACAO + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_SITUACAO_ID + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_SITUACAO +
                            " LEFT JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_CLIENTES + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_CLIENTES + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_CLIENTES_ID + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_CLIENTE +
                            " LEFT JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_FINANCEIRO + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_FINANCEIRO + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_FINANCEIRO_ID_OS + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_SEQUENCIA +
                            " LEFT JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_SERVICOS + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_SERVICOS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_SERVICO_ID_OS + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_SEQUENCIA +
                            " LEFT JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_PECAS_OS + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_PECAS_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_PECAS_OS_ID_OS + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_SEQUENCIA,

                    null, null, null, null, null, DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_SEQUENCIA + " DESC", null);
```

Comment: Talvez você precise de algum "group by" nessa sua consulta. Já verificou isso?

Comment: @acklay Você pode por favor me dá um exemplo, partindo do código que eu postei?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema usando a cláusula INSTINCT

```
 cursor = db.Select(DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + " LEFT JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_SITUACAO + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_SITUACAO + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_SITUACAO_ID + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_SITUACAO +
                        " LEFT JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_CLIENTES + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_CLIENTES + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_CLIENTES_ID + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_CLIENTE +
                        " LEFT JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_FINANCEIRO + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_FINANCEIRO + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_FINANCEIRO_ID_OS + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_SEQUENCIA +
                        " LEFT JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_SERVICOS + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_SERVICOS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_SERVICO_ID_OS + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_SEQUENCIA +
                        " LEFT JOIN " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_PECAS_OS + " ON " + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_PECAS_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_PECAS_OS_ID_OS + "=" + DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_SEQUENCIA,

                new String[]{"INSTINCT "+DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_SEQUENCIA}, null, null, null, null, DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_SEQUENCIA + " DESC", null);
```

Comment: @acklay vou considerar sua resposta Foi a prática mais segura. Depois de vários testes.